# Discord.js Role Assign and Looping Issues

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am not very efficient with my code which may be the reasons why this keeps failing. I am trying to remove and assign roles to "verified" users. The basic gist of the code is to loop through all "verified" users and assign them appropriate roles according to the data received from the API.

```html
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

var i = 0;

function mainLoop(
  guild,
  redisClient,
  users,
  main_list,
  Pilot,
  Astronaut,
  Cadet,
  main_guild,
  cadet_guild,
  guest
) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    redisClient.GET(users[i], async function (err, reply) {
      if (reply != null) {
        var json = await JSON.parse(reply);
        var uuid = Object.keys(json).shift();

        if (Object.keys(main_list).includes(uuid)) {
          var tag = users.shift();
          var rank = main_list[uuid];

          console.log(`${tag}: ${rank}`);

          var role = guild.roles.cache.find(
            (role) => role.name === `| ✧ | ${rank} | ✧ |`
          );

          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(guest);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Astronaut);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Cadet);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Pilot);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(cadet_guild);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.add(main_guild);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.add(role);
        } else {
          var tag = users.shift();
          console.log(`${tag}: Guest`);

          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Astronaut);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Cadet);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(Pilot);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(main_guild);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.remove(cadet_guild);
          await guild.members.cache.get(tag).roles.add(guest);
        }
      }
      i++;
      if (i < users.length) {
        mainLoop(
          guild,
          redisClient,
          users,
          main_list,
          Pilot,
          Astronaut,
          Cadet,
          main_guild,
          cadet_guild,
          guest
        ); 
      }
    });
  }, 5000);
}
```

The code will fetch api data, map the "verified" users and api data into an array. Then, when it starts looping through the users array, it will only log 3 times and not assign any roles. Any help would be appreciated.

**I can provide extra explanation/code if needed.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible issue I see here is that you are both incrementing the index `i` and calling `.shift()` on the `users` array. This may be the cause of the problem you are experiencing, as this will entirely skip some of the users in the array. `Array.shift()` doesn't just return the first element of the array; it removes it from the array.

Consider, for example, that your `users` array looks like this:
`var users = ["Ted", "Chris", "Ava", "Madison", "Jay"];`

And your index starts at `0` like so:
`var i = 0;`

This is what is happening in your code:

1. Assign roles for `users[i]`; the index is currently `0`, so get `users[0]` (Ted).
2. Get Ted's tag via `users.shift()`. `users` is now: `["Chris", "Ava", "Madison", "Jay"]`
3. Increment the index with `i++`. `i` is now: `1`.
4. Assign roles for `users[i]`; the index is currently `1`, so get `users[1]` (now Ava, skips Chris entirely).
5. Get Ava's tag via `users.shift()` (actually gets Chris' tag). `users` is now: `["Ava", "Madison", "Jay"]`
6. Increment the index with `i++`. `i` is now: `2`.
7. Assign roles for `users[i]`; the index is currently `2`, so get `users[2]` (now Jay, skips Madison entirely).
8. And so on, for the rest of the array; about half of the users in the `users` array will be skipped.

I don't know how many users are supposed to be in your `users` array, but this could be the reason why so few logs are occurring. Note, however, that this is just one cause of the problem you are experiencing; it is possible that there are more reasons why you are having that issue, such as rate limits.

My recommendation on how to fix this is to not use `users.shift()` to get the user's tag. Simply use `users[i]`, which will return the proper tag value without messing with the length of the array. Another way to fix this would be to remove the index incrementation, and always use `0` as your index. Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I understand now that It had been skipping over some users due to .shift() and the incrementation, so I went ahead and changed it. I'll be comparing the in-game rank list with the assigned discord roles, to see if there are still any issues. There are a total of 175 users in the users array, incremented every 5 seconds.

Would increasing the wait time to 10 seconds lower the chance of the bot being rate limited?

Comment: So every 5 seconds, you are sending a maximum of 7 role change requests to the API for the given user. The global rate limit, according to the discord [developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#global-rate-limit), is "50 requests per second." So rate limits shouldn't be a problem for you at all. In fact, you could even lower the timeout from 5 seconds to as low as a seventh of a second. I actually didn't initially notice the timeout in your code, which is why I mentioned rate limits. Rate limits shouldn't be an issue for you.